# Spring application.yaml have dash in key

Tags: spring, annotations

I want to create @Bean ExampleProperties.java and want to automatically get key/value in application.yaml, for example:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("server")
public class ExampleProperties {
    private String context-path; //this would be a mistake, cause you could not have "-" in parameter name,
}
```

How to create a parameter equals to the key in application.yml??

Answer (score 9):

According to [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding) property with dash would be represented in java as

```
@ConfigurationProperties("server")
public class ExampleProperties {
  private String contextPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me and your property looks like this :

```
my-config-map.key
```

Then you want:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-config-map")
public class Prop {

      private String key;
  
      // getter/setter

}
```